# Anyone finds [clock] useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

First of all, the clock tag has 0 followers so I'm sure nobody will miss it. Now, the usage of the tag is totally alien to me, it seems to be used for anything related to any kind of clock or time: setting up the system time, changing the visualization of the clock, questions about the RTC, questions about conky and awesome, etc.

It's unclear exactly what should I tag with this tag, and the fact that has 0 followers means that most likely nobody finds it useful for anything, I think it needs to go.

There are tags that already covers most of those topics:

- [indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/indicator) is synonym of [indicator-datetime](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/indicator-datetime) which is the name of the clock present in GNOME based desktops.
- [date-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/date-command) for the usage of the `date` command.
- each DE/WM for each visualization of the clock
- each widget (like Conky) for clocks

Anyone finds some question where the [clock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/clock) is useful?

Comment: IMO, only if there are clocks that we can install Ubuntu on. So no.

Comment: @Dan summary, "let it burn"?

Comment: My vote is yes.

Comment: Before you start pulling it there are some things we need to think about. You want each DE/Wm to have its own click tag? That seems a bit far..

Comment: @Seth "click" tag? Don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I meant clock.

Comment: @Seth [Clock](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clock) usually means the mechanical clock, if it has to be kept to be generic over some other subjects, I think `date-time` or a similar wording would make more sense.

Comment: @Seth not sure what you mean with that in that context, but what I say is: if I have an issue with the clock widget in KDE, I should tag it as [tag:kde] and done. No extra tag needed.

Comment: Take it out back and shoot it.